# RegularExpression to find uppercase links

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I'm using the RegEx below to find links in a text.
Currently links written in all caps are not found. `(e.g. HTTP://WWW.EXAMPLE.COM)`
What do I need to change?

```
var getLink:RegExp = /((https?:\/\/|www\.)[äöüÄÖÜa-zA-Z0-9\-\:\/]{1,}+\.[\*\!\'\(\)\;\:\@\&\=\$\,\?\#\%\[\]\~\-\+\_äöüÄÖÜa-zA-Z0-9\/\.]{2,}+)/g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore all case by adding the entire thing case insensitive:

`/((https?:\/\/|www\.)[äöüa-z0-9\-\:\/]{1,}+\.[\*\!\'\(\)\;\:\@\&\=\$\,\?\#\%\[\]\~\-\+\_äöüa-z0-9\/\.]{2,}+)/gi`

Notice the `i` flag at the very end. I also removed the capital letter patterns since they are no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

Add the case-insensitive `i` flag.

```
var getLink:RegExp = /((https?:\/\/|www\.)[äöüÄÖÜa-zA-Z0-9\-\:\/]{1,}+\.[\*\!\'\(\)\;\:\@\&\=\$\,\?\#\%\[\]\~\-\+\_äöüÄÖÜa-zA-Z0-9\/\.]{2,}+)/gi
```